# Swift 4 adding parameters to URLRequest completion handler

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to return some data from a URLRequest in Swift 4, and to do so I've added a completion handler to my function signature, just with a Bool for the time being. This is the function:

```
func getJson(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            print(err!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let response = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)
            print(response.results)

            // Pass results into arrays (title, abstract, url, image)
            completionHandler(true)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

and I call it in `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
getJson { (success) in
    print("Success")
}
```

Nothing is printing to the console so I'm wondering if I am using the completion handler correctly? But ultimately I'd like to switch out the Bool and instead pass a few values out of the request, back into arrays that I have in my view controller.

These are the structs I'm using to grab the pieces of JSON that i want:

```
struct TopStoriesResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let results: [Story]
}

struct Story: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
    let url: String
}
```

And I'm ultimately trying to fill these arrays in my view controller with the parsed JSON so I can arrange them in a table view:

```
var headlines = [String]()
var abstracts = [String]()
var urls = [URL]()
```

EDIT: Full code in case I'm going wrong somewhere else: https://pastebin.com/r402GKej

Comment: Does `print(response.results)` print anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't - do I have that in the wrong place?

Comment: You say "Nothing is printing to the console." None of your print statements displays anything to the console? Try adding a print statement before creating the dataTask. If it's just your completion handler that's not printing, it's because you only call the completion handler in the success case.  You should call it with a value of false in your failure case(s).

Comment: @KingTim no, but it shows that that code never gets executed. So I'm guessing data is empty.

Comment: @DuncanC adding a print statement before the data task doesn't print anything either. Now I'm really confused... no errors print either

Comment: So it must return when you create the url. Are you sure it is valid?

Comment: @Koen absolutely, I can paste the URL into my browser and it'll come up with the JSON

Comment: @Koen I've edited my question to add my full code at the bottom in case I'm messing up somewhere else

Comment: @KingTim:  print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr), can you show me the error. may be you are not able to decode correctly that's why

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary That doesn't print, so I don't think there's an error, or at least not that error

Comment: @KingTim right after the line `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in` but before the guard statement, add print lines for data, response and error. Please share the output.

Comment: @Koen No luck.. I added `print("Data: \(data), Response: \(response), Error: \(err)")` there and still no output

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the very first line of your function: `let jsonUrlString`. Then run it and single-step through your code. When you get ready to do the dataTask.resume, set a breakpoint inside the dataTask's closure at `guard let data = data`. Something you don't expect is happening. You need to figure out what.

Comment: @DuncanC It seems to be an issue with the table view... I made a new (non-tableview) project with only the structs and `getJson` function and everything prints out the way it should. Not sure why the table view is messing everything up.

Answer (score 2):

try creating the struct `TopStoriesResponse` and `Story` seperately from the ViewController and add the Networking struct to load data from the API

```
struct TopStoriesResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let copyright: String
    let num_results: Int
    let results: [Story]
}

struct Story: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
    let url: String
}

struct Networking {

    static func getJson(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            do {
                let response: TopStoriesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)
                print(response.results.count)
                completionHandler(true)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Now try calling Networking.getJson from the ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        Networking.getJson { (result) in
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's throwing an error `Use of undeclared type 'Response'` on the line `let response: Response = try JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)`

Comment: Try changing the Response to TopStoriesResponse in getJson method

Comment: Alright so it seems to be an issue with my table view. I made a new Xcode project (non tableview) and it your solution (as well as my code in my initial post) worked to print the results to the console. Not sure why the table view is messing that up. But my original question was how to get the headlines, abstracts etc out of the data request and into the arrays that I had set up. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: You can return the TopStoriesResponse in completion handler which has result parameter which contains all the Stories. You can show these stories in table view. If you want to create separate arrays then you need to iterate on stories and create these arrays for headlines, urls etc. I think you should use stories array to display in cell

Comment: Your solution and my initial code just get the `response.results` from the request, in other words all the headlines, abstracts and urls together. How would I grab those things separately and put them into my cell? I figured arranging them into my arrays and going from there was the best approach but I'm open to something else. This is my full code so you can see the table view methods as well: https://pastebin.com/r402GKej